# setting a UTF-8 in java and csv file

Tags: java, unicode, csv, utf-8, opencsv

I am using this code for add Persian words to a csv file via [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net):

```
String[] entries="\u0645 \u062E\u062F\u0627".split("#");
try{
    CSVWriter writer=new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\test.csv"), "UTF-8"));

    writer.writeNext(entries);
    writer.close();
}
catch(IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I open the resulting csv file, in Excel, it contains **"ứỶờịỆ"**. Other programs such as notepad.exe don't have this problem, but all of my users are using MS Excel.

Replacing OpenCSV with [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) does not solve this problem.

When I typed Persian characters into csv file manually, I don't have any problems.

Comment: Definitely an exact duplicate. I just tried this problem with the solution from the link above (use a BOM to make Excel read in UTF-8) and it solved this problem. Alternatively, apparently using UTF-16 works as well to force Excel to read the CSV not in ASCII.

Comment: There is a useful link similar to AlexR's post !
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joconner/archive/2010/03/24/writing-csv-files-utf-8-excel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, CSV is a very ad hoc format with no metadata and no real standard that would mandate a flexible encoding. As long as you use CSV, you can't reliably use any characters outside of ASCII.

Your alternatives:

- Write to XML (which does have encoding metadata if you do it right) and have the users [import the XML](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/import-xml-data-HP010206405.aspx) into Excel.
- Use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to create actual Excel documents.

Comment: XML and POI are fine but CSV works too. Please see my comment. I managed to create CSV file that contains unicode symbols and can be opened with MS excel.

Comment: @AlexR: That may or may not work for any given version of Excel or other programs, or it could cause the file to be rejected as invalid, or put some spurious characters into the first cell. Your program's behaviour should not rely on undocumented features.

Comment: @AlexR Can you help me.I have similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66331230/unable-to-display-chinese-characters-in-excel-using-csv-bean-writer

Answer (score 126):

I spent some time but found solution for your problem.

First I opened notepad and wrote the following line: שלום, hello, привет
Then I saved it as file he-en-ru.csv using UTF-8.
Then I opened it with MS excel and everything worked well.

Now, I wrote a simple java program that prints this line to file as following:

```
    PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    w.print(line);
    w.flush();
    w.close();
```

When I opened this file using excel I saw "gibrish."

Then I tried to read content of 2 files and (as expected) saw that file generated by notepad contains 3 bytes prefix:

```
    239 EF
    187 BB
    191 BF
```

So, I modified my code to print this prefix first and the text after that:

```
    String line = "שלום, hello, привет";
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("c:/temp/j.csv");
    os.write(239);
    os.write(187);
    os.write(191);

    PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

    w.print(line);
    w.flush();
    w.close();
```

And it worked! I opened the file using excel and saw text as I expected.

Bottom line: write these 3 bytes before writing the content. This prefix indicates that the content is in 'UTF-8 with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)' (otherwise it is just 'UTF-8 without BOM').

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8

Comment: Thank you for scientific description. Good to know...

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Excel did you use for your test?

Comment: Worked for me as well. I'm keeping that one in my back pocket!

Comment: Great solution. I am now having the similar issue, but with Chinese characters, shown as "???". Would you offer me some suggestions on the three bytes?

Comment: Still works in 2014! Spasibo!

Comment: how you read those 3 bytes? where are they visible?

Comment: This pointed me in the correct direction for solving this problem in a Spring Boot context, where I get the OutputStream from the response Object. See this question:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46296827/java-spring-returning-csv-file-encoded-in-utf-8-with-bom/57854305#57854305)

Comment: @AlexR Can you help me I have a similar question in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66331230/unable-to-display-chinese-characters-in-excel-using-csv-bean-writer

Answer (score 4):

Excel doesn't use `UTF8` to open CSV files. Thats a known problem. The actual encoding used depends on the locale settings of Microsoft Windows. With a German lcoale for example Excel would open a CSV file with `CP1252`.

You could create an Excel file containing some persian characters and save it as an CSV file. Then write a small Java program to read this file and test some common encodings. Thats the way I used to figure out the correct encoding for German umlauts in CSV files.

Comment: Unfortunately it is wrong. I managed to create CSV file with unicode symbols that can be opened with excel. See my comment later