# CSV file with japanese characters not opening properly in Excel 2007

Tags: java, jsp, unicode, download

I have a **simple JSP** to download a csv file containing **Japanese** characters. Downloaded file opens correctly in **notepad++** and shows right characters but when I try to open same file in **Excel 2007**, It shows some different characters, probably in some other encoding.

My JSP looks like this.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/csv; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%  
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + "Test.csv");
    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();   
    System.out.println("Chaaracter encoding : " + response.getCharacterEncoding()); 
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output,"UTF-8"));

    String japanese = "注目のキーワード";   
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(japanese.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));                  
    String line = null;                 
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.write(line);
        writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }           
    reader.close(); 
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
%>
```

This string in Excel 2007 looks like this : **æ³¨ç›®ã®ã‚­ãƒ¼ãƒ¯ãƒ¼ãƒ‰**

Could any one please help me here. User should be able to directly open file in Excel when he clicks on download link(above jsp).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Jitendra

Comment: Duplicate of [setting a UTF-8 in java and csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192186/setting-a-utf-8-in-java-and-csv-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already answered similar question. Please read here: [setting a UTF-8 in java and csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192186/setting-a-utf-8-in-java-and-csv-file/4192897#4192897). Generally the problem can be solved by putting "magic" code (know as Byte Order Mark) in the beginning of the file.

Comment: You are right. It was magic for me cause I did not know what is this.