# Java. Appending string to file, ended with strange output

Tags: java, file, file-io, filewriter

I have the following simple function to append text to some txt file. The length of the text in the code is 1024:

```
void AppendToFile(String filename)
{
    String text = "0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,";
    System.out.println(text);

    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true)));
        out.println(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

The printing to the console works fine. However, when I open the file - it seems like

```
ⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱ਍
```

For shorter string, like:

```
String text = "0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1";
```

or for another very long string, e.g., 1024 times 'a' it works fine (so the reason is not the length of the string).

I can't understand this. Do you have any explanation?

Comment: It may be an encoding issue: 1. You should specify an encoding (e.g. UTF-8) 2. In what reader do you open the file?

Comment: Notepad. If this is an encoding issue, why I can read the short string (it is just some prefix of the text)?

Comment: Works ok on Ubuntu, using Gedit to read file

Comment: I run it on Windows 7 (64 bit) with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `Notepad`. I believe it is *still* incorrectly detecting the encoding, although [Wikipedia claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29#Unicode_detections) this is fixed in Windows 7.

In all my tests I compiled and run with Java 1.6.0_45 on Windows 7 64-bit. Also the system property `file.encoding = Cp1252`.

With your original code, the file produced is detected by Sublime Text as `UTF-8` but (importantly) the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) is missing. Opening the same file in Notepad shows the character placeholder square. Re-saving the file in Sublime Text with the BOM then opening in Notepad gives the expected characters.

Replacing `0`s **and** `,`s with `a`s and opening in Notepad, I see Chinese (I think) characters which fits in with the Wikipedia information as I guess I have the correct font. So the encoding is detected incorrectly. Attempting to *Save as* the Notepad file, the encoding listed is `Unicode` which is really `UTF-16 Little Endian (UTF-16LE)` - see [Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

Replacing `0`s with `a`s and opening in Notepad, I see squares again, since the incorrectly detected encoding has not matched a valid character.

Replacing all characters with `a`s works because the detected encoding is `ANSI`. You can see this by trying a *Save as* in Notepad and observing the *Encoding* drop down.

From [How to add a UTF-8 BOM in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389005/how-to-add-a-utf-8-bom-in-java), I added `out.write('\ufeff');` to write the BOM before the `out.println(text);`, but with my default encoding the result in Notepad started with a `?` since again Notepad was failing to correctly detect the encoding. It was again detected as `ANSI`, although at least the rest of the characters displayed as expected.

Adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` **and** `out.write('\ufeff');` finally produced a file that Notepad could decode and display as expected.

Answer (score 0):

FileWriter uses the system default encoding and in your case which is probably is NOT set to UTF-8. One way of fixing this problem by setting system property

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

which will make FileWriter to use UTF-8

Comment: @radimpe The example shorter strings mentioned are not dependent on UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: So "0,1,0,1,0...." for 1024 characters is UTF-8 while "0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1" is not UTF-8? Quite puzzled.

Comment: I followed the instructions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding/623036#623036 to change the settings. It still doesn't work. (I get the 'Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8' as expected in the console).

Answer (score 0):

This is more than likely an issue with Notepad.

Notepad (at least on Windows 7, where I've replicated your issue) has a max line length of 1024 characters. By adding another 0 to the end of your string it prints fine, although it wraps the last character onto a new line.

It is also unlikely to be an encoding issue since by replacing all 0s with As and all 1s with Bs you actually get a similar error:

```
 ⱡⱢⱡⱡⱢⱡⱢⱢⱢⱡⱢⱡⱢⱡⱡⱢⱡⱢⱢⱢⱡⱢⱢⱡⱢⱡⱢⱢⱢⱢⱡⱢⱡⱢⱡⱡⱢⱢⱢⱢⱡⱢⱡⱡⱡⱡⱡⱢⱢⱢⱡⱢⱢⱡⱢⱡⱢⱡⱢⱢⱡ
```

Again adding or removing a character, will print fine.