# UTF8 characters showing weirdly or random basis in Android TextView

Tags: java, android, utf-8, textview

It has been at least 5 applications in which I have attempted to display UTF8 encoded characters and every time, quite sporadically and rarely I see random characters being replaced by diamond question marks (see image for better details).

I enclose a page layout to demonstrate my issues. The layout is very basic, it is very simple poll I am creating. The "Съгласен съм" text is takes from a database, where it has just been inserted by a script, using copy-pasted constant. The text is displayed in `TextView`s.

[image]

Has anyone ever encountered such an issue? Please advise!

EDIT: Something I forgot to mention is that the amount and position of weird characters varies on diffferent Android Phone models.

Comment: What DBMS is this? SQLite?

Comment: @user3249477 standard Android SQLite it is local on-device DB.

Comment: Have you checked the database manually, if the string is saved properly?

Comment: @user3249477 It looks like when i open in editor, but is there a chance that some editors handle some weird cases. Furthermore not always when i have observed the weird diamond Database was interfered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it all sorted out in all my applications. Actually the issues mlet down to 3 different reasons and I will list all of them below so that this findings of mine could help people in the future.

**Reason 1:** ***Incorrect encoding of user created file.***

This actually was the problem with the application I posted about in the question. The problem was that the encoding of the insert script I used for introducing the values in the database was "UTF8 without BOM". I converted this encoding to "UTF8" using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and reinserted the values in the database and the issue was resolved. Thanks to @user3249477 for pointing me to thinking in this direction. *By the way "UTF8 without BOM" seems to be the default encoding Eclipse uses when creating URF8 files, so take care!*

**Reason 2:** ***Incorrect encoding of generated file.***

The problem of reason 1, pointed me to what to think for in some of the other cases I was facing. In one application of mine I am provided with raw data that I insert in my backend database using simple Java application. The problem there turned out to be that I was passing through intermediate format, files stored on the file system that ?I used to verify I interpretted the raw data correctly. I noticed that these files were also created "UTF8 without BOM". I used this code to write to these files:

```
BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath)); 
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, STRING_ENCODING)); 
writer.append(string);
```

Which I changed to:

```
BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath)); 
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, STRING_ENCODING)); 
// prepending a bom 
writer.write('\ufeff'); 
writer.append(string);
```

Following the prescriptions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8120786/1108032). This line I add basically made all the intermediate files be encoded in "UTF8" with BOM and resolved my encoding issues.

**Reason 3:** ***Incorrect parsing of HTTP responses***

The last issue I encountered in few of my applications was that I was not interpretting the UTF8 http responses correctly. I used to have the following code:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(host, request, (HttpContext) null);
String responseBody = null;
responseBody = IOHelper.getInputStreamContents(responseStream);
```

Where `IOHelper` is an util I have written myself and reads stream contents to `String`. I replaced this code with the already provided method in the Android API:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(host, request, (HttpContext) null);
String responseBody = null;
if (response.getEntity() != null) { 
    responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8); 
}
```

And this fixed the encoding issues I was having with HTTP responses.

---

As conclusion I can say that one needs to take special care of BOM / without BOM strings when using UTF8 encoding in Android. I am very happy I learnt so many new things during this investigation.