# CSV Java Generated Files Are Opened With Incorrect Charset

Tags: java, csv, utf-8

Below is the java code used to generate the CSV file. Although while debugging this `report.getEncoding()` acquires the value of "UTF-8", the file is generated with an incorrect charset.

```
public void generateFile(ReportBean<T> report, String filename, ReportAggregationPosition reportAggregationPosition) throws IOException {
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), report.getEncoding()))) {
        List<T> filteredResult = new ArrayList();
        for (T row : report.getResult()) {
            if (logRow(row)) {
                log.info("Logging row for report={} - {}", filename, getText(row));
            }
            if (ignoreRow(row)) {
                log.info("Ignoring row for report={} - {}", filename, getText(row));
                continue;
            }
            filteredResult.add(row);
        }
        if (reportAggregationPosition == ReportAggregationPosition.FIRST) {
            out.println(filteredResult.size());
        }
        out.print(getHeader());
        if (reportAggregationPosition == ReportAggregationPosition.SECOND) {
            out.println(filteredResult.size());
        }
        for (T row : filteredResult) {
            out.print(getText(row));
        }
        if (reportAggregationPosition == ReportAggregationPosition.LAST) {
            out.println(String.format("Total number of rows: %s", filteredResult.size()));
        }
    }
```

The expected value is:

> test-vfde - The hidden edition - Gebühr pro Benutzer Leistungszeit 07/07/16 bis 08/05/16

But the value that is shown (I couldn't upload a photo as I still don't have credits) is the following one:

> test-vfde - The hidden edition - GebÇŸ’?Ç?¶¬hr pro Benutzer Leistungszeit 07/07/16 bis 08/05/16

Characters as "ä" or "ü" are shown correctly. How should I approach this?

Comment: *"the value that is shown"* Shown where?

Comment: Are you sure that the writer has the wrong charset and not the reader you're opening it with?

Comment: Andreas. I stil can't upload a CSV file but in the CSV file as stated by the subject.

Comment: ManuToMatic. I was debuggin and UTF8 was the charset used to generate the file... Although when the client uses Microsoft Excel or NotePad++, the values shown are incorrectly... For instance Instead of "ü" it's show "ÇŸ"

Comment: Using UTF-8, I _do_ get the correct values in NotePadd++. It would help if you made a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following lines

```
.....
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), report.getEncoding()))) {
    out.write(0xef);
    out.write(0xbb);
    out.write(0xbf);
    List<T> filteredResult = new ArrayList();
    .....
```

Description can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389005/how-to-add-a-utf-8-bom-in-java)

Comment: Uzochi. Thankx for the answer. I realized that in many parts of the application the same code is applied before the content is written... The thing here is that I can't reproduce it so I'll have to think in a way of testing this but not locally... I'll keep you update my friend... cheers