# Flex fileReference save in utf-8 with BOM encoding format

Tags: apache-flex, utf-8, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

I want to save a file in utf-8 encoding format (NOT utf-8 without BOM). There is no explicit information on Adobe Charset support page

(http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/charset-codes.html)

I want to save the file in utf-8 format with csv extension. I have tried the following but i am getting what i want:

```
byte.writeMultiBytes(fileContent,"utf-8");
```

I have also tried,

unicode-1-1-utf-8,
unicode-2-0-utf-8, 
x-unicode-2-0-utf-8.

I have also tried with other methods as well but still not getting the required encoding format:

writeUTF(var:String)
writeByte(var:String)

Here's what I have right now,

```
var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();  
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

// SAVING file in utf-8 encoding format.
bytes.writeUTFBytes(this.fileContents);
fileReference.save(bytes, "PluginLog.csv");
closePopup(null);
```

Comment: I have found the answer to my question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192186/setting-a-utf-8-in-java-and-csv-file/4192897#4192897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer intuidev points to helped me as well. It shows the answer in Java. Here's how I reproduced it in Actionscript:

```
public function writeFileWithUTF8Bom(data:String, fileName:String):void {
    var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
    var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    // Include the byte order mark for UTF-8
    b.writeByte(0xEF);
    b.writeByte(0xBB);
    b.writeByte(0xBF);
    b.writeUTFBytes(data);
    fileRef.save(b, fileName);          
}
```