# create CSV file with Hebrew Text

Tags: android, csv, opencsv

I am writing CSV file using below code.

```
FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PATH+"/"+EXPORT_CONTACT_FILE_NAME);

    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(fWriter);
    List<String[]> dataThis = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for(InviteDataClass inviteData : data){
          if(inviteData.getItemType() == TaskDataClass.SECTION){
              dataThis.add(new String[] {inviteData.getName()});
          }else{
              dataThis.add(new String[] {inviteData.getName(), inviteData.getFamilyName(),String.valueOf(inviteData.getNoOfInvites()),String.valueOf(inviteData.getApprove()),inviteData.getEmail(),inviteData.getAddress(),String.valueOf(inviteData.getVegetarian()),String.valueOf(inviteData.getVegan()),String.valueOf(inviteData.getDisabled()),String.valueOf(inviteData.getChild()),String.valueOf(inviteData.getBabies()),String.valueOf(inviteData.getInVitationSent()),String.valueOf(inviteData.getActuallyReached()),inviteData.getGigt(),inviteData.getPhone()});
          }

     }
writer.writeAll(dataThis);

        writer.close();
```

I am write Hebrew text to csv file but I get below text in file.

```
×œ×œ× ×§×˜×’×•×¨×™×”
```

Please help me.

Comment: Check this solution , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192186/setting-a-utf-8-in-java-and-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify encoding anywhere. You should always explicitly specify it when you write or read strings to/from a file.

I'm pretty sure that the CSVWriter you use has a method to fix the encoding.

Comment: I have not any method to set encoding type in CSVWriter.

Comment: Then switch libraries or patch it if it's open source.