# Japanese character not showing properly converting CSV file

Tags: java, csv, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am converting CSV file from [Tatoeba](http://tatoeba.org/eng/home) project. It contains Japanese characters. I am inserting data into SQLite database. Insertion is going without a problem, but characters are showing not properly.
If I insert directly:

```
            String str = content_parts[2];
            sentence.setValue(str);
```

Getting values like this:

> ãã¿ã«ã¡ãã£ã¨ãããã®ããã£ã¦ãããã

I have tried to decode to UTF8 from JIS:

```
            String str = content_parts[2];
            byte[] utf8EncodedBytes = str.getBytes("JIS");
            String s = new String(utf8EncodedBytes, "UTF-8");
            sentence.setValue(s);
```

JIS:

> $B!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!r!)!)!/!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!r!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)!)(B

Shift-JIS:

> ????\??????�N?�}??????????????????��?????�N?�N???��??????

Shift_JIS:

> ????\????????????????????????��?�N??????????????????��??????

CSV file (when opened by Excel 2010)

> n гЃЌгЃїгЃ«гЃЎг‚‡гЃЈгЃЁгЃ—гЃџг‚‚гЃ®г‚’г‚‚гЃЈгЃ¦гЃЌгЃџг‚€гЂ‚

What I am doing wrong? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Which encoding does the text in the file use?

Comment: May be the issue is with the database encoding, not with java display

Comment: @immibis, honestly, i do not know. now i am searching for how to identify encoding

Comment: @ortis, I have tried to System.out.println(s). Database and values in console are same

Comment: Well, if you cant display correct word within DB client, it is probably a databse encoding issue. Check if the encoding is UTF8

Comment: @immibis, I found out that file encoding is UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

If you are still searching for solution, refer below link

[setting-a-utf-8-in-java-and-csv-file and handle Japanese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192186/setting-a-utf-8-in-java-and-csv-file/4192897#4192897)

[csv-reports-not-displaying-japanese-characters](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/817837/csv-reports-not-displaying-japanese-characters)

In brief, add BOM(byte order mark) characters to your file outputstream before passing it to outputstream writer.

String content="some string to write in file(in any language)";

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\csvFile.csv");

fos.write(239);

fos.write(187);

fos.write(191);

Writer w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

w.write(content);

w.close();

Hope this will help