# Creating csv file with utf-8

Tags: csv, android-studio, utf-8

I have a problem with my Csv file, In my app I want to insert all the data base to a Csv file and send it via email.
Every thing goes great except one thing- the encoding of the file isn't UTF-8
so every time I send the file via email I have to change the encoding my self.

I didn't find any way I can change the encoding when I create the file,
so I wanna know if it is possible to insert a csv file to the resource folder in my app with encoding UTF-8,
and then send this file via email.

So what I am asking is, Is it possible?
And if so, how can I do it?

I am currently creating the csv file with openCSV

  `String csv = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                try {
                    File myFile = new File(csv + "/Data.csv");
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(myFile), ',');
}`

Comment: I searched for a long time,
I didn't find an answer.
do you have an example I can see?

Comment: I am not reading the csv file in my phone,
I am just creating and writing in it,
then I send it to an email and open the file in my computer.

I don't know where you found the answer,
but I cant find any piece of code that changes the encoding,
maybe im an idiot, Idk ):.
Can you send me a link of the answer you found?

Comment: Ok tell me if I am right,
this code creates a file reader that reads the file with UTF-8 encoding,
so when I want to get a line or something from the csv file Ill get the string or the line with UTF-8 encoding and use it in my code or what ever...

If this is the thing that code does It wont help.
When I open the File in my computer the default encoding isn't UTF-8
and every time I send the file via email I have to change the encoding(in my computer)
If this code you sent me suppose to do what I said then it didn't work ):
And I don't know why....
and ty for the help anyways

Comment: Thank you very much,
But it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: The last link you sent me had no effect...
Ill try this last link you sent

Comment: Ok Thank you very much,
this link worked.
And thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the lengthy comments we exchanged while searching a solution to your problem.

You have to use a different constructor on `CSVWriter`, then you are able to specify the file encoding.
Defining the `file.encoding` when the JVM gets launched should help too:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar foo.jar
```

There is already a documented solution to your problem on stack overflow which shows an example: [setting a UTF-8 in java and csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192186/setting-a-utf-8-in-java-and-csv-file)