# How to encode Strings in a Hashmap to output hyphens

Tags: java, utf-8, hashmap

I have a hashmap containing a key and some values, such as:

```
final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
{
    map.put("01", "Example – Description");
    map.put("02", "Example – Description")
}
```

The value, description, in the hashmap contains a hyphen and when outputting to a CSV file it isn't being displayed correctly and instead shows 'x96'. I understand there is some encoding here that needs to be done - UTF-8?

My question is, how do you do this for a hashmap?

I am accessing these values in a method like this:

```
add[0] = updateSomething[0] + " " + map.get(e.getKey());
```

Comment: how do you write the string to the CSV? we need to know in order to help you

Comment: Hi David, I am just using the writer and calling the writeNext method adding the value in through a new String Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force UTF-8, specify the JVM file encoding using:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 … com.x.Main
```

See [Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

After you've done that, make sure you are opening the CSV with UTF-8 encoding as well.

See [setting a UTF-8 in java and csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192186/setting-a-utf-8-in-java-and-csv-file)

Comment: Thanks, did the job