# Unable to display Chinese characters in excel using CSV Bean Writer

Tags: java, excel, export-to-csv

I am using ICsvBeanWriter to export data as CSV and i am trying to open it in Excel.But I am unable to view Chinese characters in Excel by default.But if i load the csv file and change encoding from Western European to 65001 Unicode(UTF-8) then i am able to see Chinese characters displayed in excel.So my question is "Is it possible to open excel with default UTF-8 encoding? Here is my code

**Controller.java**

```
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=Report " + downloadDateFormatted + ".csv");
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION);
    **response.setContentType("text/csv;charset=UTF-8");**
    CsvExporter csvExporter = new CsvExporter(transactions);
    csvExporter.export(response);
```

**CsvExporter.java**

```
    public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
       csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(response.getWriter(), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
       writeHeaderRow();
    }

    private void writeHeaderRow() throws IOException {
    String[] csvHeader = {"Chinese address" };
            csvWriter.writeHeader(csvHeader);
    String[] nameMapping = { "chineseAddress" };
    csvWriter.write(transaction, nameMapping);
    }
    csvWriter.close();
    }
```

I tried setting charset to utf-8 but still it is opening in Western European encoding in Excel by default.I tried with UTF-16.But still same result.When i open in other editors like notepad chinese characters are displayed perfectly but not working in Excel

Comment: Perhaps you should consider saving the original output in the correct coding. I do this with BBEdit...

Comment: @SolarMike Can you please elaborate?

Comment: BBEdit has an encoding choice box when doing save as. Choose the encoding necessary. Not sure what “elaboration” you need.

Comment: @SolarMike I am looking for something code level where i can set encoding and open excel in UTF-8

Comment: I think BBEdit can be driven by code, tell it to open a file then save as needed...

Comment: Do not use Excel to read CSV files. Excel is a very powerfull tool, but as CSV is not a Microsoft specific format, it only has an awful support for it. You'd better use LibreOffice calc because it allows to specify the encoding at read time. I know this is not the expected answer (hence a comment) but I am afraid it is the best I can do here...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `UTF-8` and adding `\uFEFF` at the very start of the file .

This is the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) used by Excel to also identify UTF-8 encoded files (not only the byte order).

Code used to do a quick test:

```
var writer = new FileWriter("/tmp/a.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
writer.write("\uFEFF");  // BOM
writer.write("test:,\u4E2D,ok");  // or writer.write("test:,中,ok");
writer.close();
```

In Excel:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But in the line var writer = new FileWriter("/tmp/a.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8); here we need to specify file path right? I dont have any specific file path.I am just passing it as httpservlet response as you can see in my code.

Comment: Can you tell me what is this line of code is meant for writer.write("test:,\u4E2D,ok"); ?

Comment: I modified code like this Writer writer = response.getWriter();
  writer.write("\uFEFF");
  csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(writer, CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);  .But still i am not able to see Chinese characters displayed.It is displaying something like this æ€€æŸ”

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229147/discussion-between-sachin-hr-and-user15244370).