# MySQL: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE0' in utf8mb4 column

Tags: mysql, laravel, utf8mb4, character-set

I'm getting errors when certain characters are being added to a table... even when the column is has `utf8mb4` character set. For example:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE0' for column 'surname'`

The data in question is: **SEGAL‡** (note the [double dagger](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2021/index.htm))

Is this character beyond even 4 byte UTF8 or is the collation causing the issue? Or is it something else?

Screenshot showing character set and collation of the column:

[image: screenshot showing utf8mb4 character set]

It's a Laravel 8 app and the MySQL connection is configured to the following:

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

Looking at the CSV file in PHPStorm, non-ASCII characters are displayed as `�`. I've tried explicitly setting the file encoding to UTF-8 in PHPStorm (with and without BOM).

If I open the CSV in Excel then the non-ASCII characters display correctly. Confused.

### Update

Examining the CSV in a HEX editor shows that a character like `ä` is stored as a single byte (`8A`). When this CSV is opened in Excel it correctly shows `ä`, but in everything else it shows `�`.

I don't know what character encoding Excel is using, as this character should be typically stored as `E4` when using a single byte, or `C3 A4` in UTF-8.

Comment: What is the `collation`? This should also be a `utf8mb4_` subset. You need to check both your connection character set and collation as well as the database/table/data.

Comment: @Martin The collation is visible in the screenshot: `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`

Comment: It may be visible but it was not identified `:-p` . So what's your database user connection character set? Have you [**read this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)?

Comment: @Martin Updated with more information

Comment: Your CSV file may need a Byte Order Mark on it (BOM)  [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192186/setting-a-utf-8-in-java-and-csv-file) . Regenerate your CSV with one and see if that works?

Comment: @Martin Updated again. Confused.

Comment: Ok, well I've looked up the sequence you posted (`\xE0`) and online character tables can't find it. If the sequence you post is not a legitimate UTF-8 character then obviously it won't display. Can you change all your parts to UTF-16 perhaps to see if that extended set would correctly show it? Either in the source file (not via Excel) or on the database.

Comment: Further, the character you display appears to be Unicode character `U+2021` . I don't think you need UTF-16, I can find this character on UTF-8 catalogues. I can't edit my comment now.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your help. I believe Excel is to blame during the export (although I can't fathom what encoding it's using). I've opened a new question about editing the VB script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double dagger is hex E2 80 A1 (only 3 bytes) when encoded in `CHARACTER SET` utf8 or utf8mb4.  It is also available in latin1 as hex 87.

C3A4 [ä]LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS (in utf8/utf8mb4) or E4 in latin1.

Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

See "black diamond" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for the likely cause.

The `CHARACTER SET` is the "encoding" and is relevant; the `COLLATION` is how characters compare (eg case-folding) and is not relevant.

Nothing in the Question hints of a BOM (http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#bom_byte_order_mark) EF BB BF at the beginning of *some* UTF-8-encoded files.

Do not use ucs-2 (UTF-16) unless you happen to have a file encoded that way.  Still, I would declare the tables as utf8, not ucs-2.

**More**

I plugged `8AE0E8` into a handy script (that does `CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('8ae0e8') USING %s) USING utf8mb4)` and got:

```
ascii, big5, binary, cp932, eucjpms, euckr,
    gb18030, gb2312, gbk, sjis, ujis,
    utf8mb3, utf8mb4   ---invalid in these charsets
                                     swe7   3  3 '???'
                                   cp1257   5  3 '?ąč'
                                   cp1256   5  3 '?àè'
                                  geostd8   5  3 '?ჭ?'
                                   latin7   6  3 'ąč'
                             dec8, latin5   6  3 'àè'
                                      hp8   6  3 'ÁÒ'
                                    macce   6  3 'äŗŤ'
                                    cp850   6  3 'èÓÞ'
                                  keybcs2   6  3 'ĹαΦ'
                                    cp852   6  3 'ŐÓŔ'
                                   latin2   6  3 'ŕč'
                                   latin1   6  3 'Šàè'
                                   cp1250   6  3 'Šŕč'
                                    greek   6  3 'ΰθ'
                                    cp866   6  3 'Крш'
                                   cp1251   6  3 'Љаи'
                                 armscii8   6  3 'ՈՌ'
                                   hebrew   6  3 'אט'
                             koi8r, koi8u   7  3 '┼ЮХ'
                                 macroman   7  3 'ä‡Ë'
                                   tis620   8  3 'เ่'
```

It looks like `macroman` is the charset.  I think that is specific to Apple.

Comment: I can't deduce what encoding this file (generated by Excel) is using: `ä` = `8A`. `‡` = `E0`. `Ë` = `E8`. If I can get the file in UTF-16, I could then manually convert it to UTF-8.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt - I added further analysis.

Comment: Ah, MacRoman... That is incredibly helpful. Thank you!

Comment: `SET NAMES maxroman` to declare that the _client_ is using that; meanwhile, continue to have columns declared as utf8mb4.